# Python Conditional (IF, ELSE) Indentation Exception

Tags: python, scrapy, indentation, conditional-statements, craigslist

I am working on my first Python project and am using the Scrapy.org framework. I am attempting to use an IF statement to determine if price is empty so it doesn't store in my CSV file.

For some reason I am receiving a indentation exception.

**IndentationError: expected an indented block**

The IF statement is located at the end of this code snippet.

Thank you all for taking the time to help me out!

Code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "craig"
allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
start_urls = [
'http://longisland.craigslist.org/search/sss?sort=date&query=raptor+660&srchType=T',
'http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/sss?zoomToPosting=&query=raptor+660&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=&sort=date',
'http://hudsonvalley.craigslist.org/search/sss?zoomToPosting=&query=raptor+660&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=&sort=date',
'http://newjersey.craigslist.org/search/sss?zoomToPosting=&query=raptor+660&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=&sort=date',
'http://hartford.craigslist.org/search/sss?zoomToPosting=&query=raptor+660&srchType=T&minAsk=&maxAsk=&sort=date'
]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//p")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        #item["date"] = titles.select('span[@class="itemdate"]/text()').extract()
        item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        item ["price"] = titles.select('span[@class="itempnr"]/span[@class="itempp"]/text()').extract()
        if not items ["price"]:
            #do nothing
        else:
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: I'm assuming the code after `class` not being indented is a problem with creating the code sample. Please fix it, and check your code samples for formatting *before* posting, **especially** with Python. (Where it's impossible for anyone else to know how it's really supposed to be.)

Comment: Also, you should reduce your code samples. In this one, 80% of it (everything except the `if..else` block) is irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if`, `else`, `for`, `def` etc. **must** be followed by a code block. A comment doesn't count. This is what the [`pass` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is for:

```
if not item["price"]:
    pass
else:
    items.append(item)
```

That said, why not just invert the condition?

```
if item["price"]:
    items.append(item)
```

Comment: thanks. I had to make a small revision to your suggestion but it worked. if item["price"]:

Comment: @JoeBarreca I was going by the code in your original question, so you should probably also fix the typo there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:

```
    if not items ["price"]:
        #do nothing
    else:
        items.append(item)
```

...you can't have just a comment where indented statements are expected. Python has a keyword that's for exactly this case -- `pass`:

```
    if not items ["price"]:
        #do nothing
        pass
    else:
        items.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went through this tutorial http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_2.6/Decisions and didn't see pass mentioned anywhere.. Sorry for being a noob.. -1 stinks :(

Comment: The best thing about newbieness is that it's a temporary state. The classic tutorial is this one: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ -- see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

Answer (score 2):

If the if does nothing and you're only using the else you probably want to use its negation. If you are just testing, you  need to add a `pass` into it:

```
if True:
  pass  # just a comment here does not work
else:
  dostuff()
```